# How to identify a variable-sized zone by a point given by coordinate?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, algorithms

The Cartesian plane is partitioned into zones of variable sizes.

A zone is always a rectangle. For example, a zone can be represented like $x \in (0, 3], y \in (30, 50]$

The range in the Cartesian plane is finite but very large.

Then, when given an x,y-coordinate, how can we identify the zone that coordinate belongs to?

For example, when we have an x,y-coordinate (2, 36), how do we effectively find that this belongs to the zone  $x \in (0, 3], y \in (30, 50]$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best algorithm is a linear time algorithm where you compare the query point for every zone. The reason is, if the zones are overlapping a query point can be in $O(N)$ zones. So $O(N)$ operation is necessary.

However if the zones are non-overlapping and a query point can be in only one zone then, I think by using kd-tree you can find the zone by spending 
$O(N log N)$ pre-processing time and $O(N^{1/2})$ query time.